# Javascript: how to use multiple play buttons in audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

So i'm trying to use two play `buttons` in my `audio` player, this is because i have one in audio player and other in sidebar for example.

**Follows my jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LqM9D/5/

Someone can help?

Obs: i'm using html5 audio and jquery/js on my player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're re-using the same ID twice. IDs **must** be unique. Correct that and it works fine. And since you're using jQuery, you could use:

```
window.player = $('#player')[0];
$('#playpause, #playpause2').click(function () {
    if (player.paused) {
        player.play();
        this.innerHTML = 'pause';
    } else {
        player.pause();
        this.innerHTML = 'play';
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LqM9D/9/)**

Comment: @j08691 niceeee!!!!! really thanks!!! and how i can do button1 turn to pause, when the button2 is clicked to play? can you help about this?

Comment: So when clicking button two, would both buttons turn to pause?

Comment: when clicking the button two, the button one is stoped and this text is "play" showing that he is paused, just one button can be in playing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a common class on your buttons, instead of ids. IDs need to be unique. Then set jQuery click method. Updated

Answer (score -1):

i have a similar question. I would like to list multiple play buttons and be able to use a listenEvent to trigger play and pause for each. However I can't seem to wrap my head around it. It works fine when I code the first button but when I try to introduce a second player it breaks.
I wish to keep my audio tags as html and call them in the js.
Here is a link so it's more understandable
https://codepen.io/my-mosas/pen/WNzvoGY `0123`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32158326)